# Item is not saving, changing back to its original state after re-clicking edit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue.js, when clicking the button to edit it edits fine, but when I click it back it just changes it back to how the text was before the edit. For example in the box it says Chicken, I press edit and I put Rice and press edit again it will change it back to Chicken.

```
<tr v-for="(foodItem, index) in filteredFoodItems" :key="index">
   <td>
       <input v-bind:value="foodItem.name" v-bind:class="{'is-static': !foodItem.editing}" type="text" class="input">
   </td>
   <td>
        <input v-bind:value="foodItem.price | currency('£')" v-bind:class="{'is-static': !foodItem.editing}" type="text" class="input">
   </td>
   <td>
        <input v-bind:value="foodItem.category" v-bind:class="{'is-static': !foodItem.editing}" type="text" class="input">
   </td>
   <td>
```

That is the input fields, this is the button I am currently using -

```
<button class="button is-fullwidth" v-on:click="foodItem.editing = !foodItem.editing" v-bind:value="foodItem.editing ? 'Save': 'Edit'">Edit</button>
```

Also, the button does not change to save it keeps itself as edit.

Comment: click back from where ? where is it going in the first place? this is very unclear

Comment: When I click the edit button, I edit the text and then I click the Edit button again to save changes, but it just sets the text back to its original state.

Comment: because you are not using v-model ?

Comment: I inserted the v-model into each of them and it is now saving, but the button is not changing whiles I edit to save, like its supposed to do? many thanks!

Comment: `<button class="button is-fullwidth" v-on:click="foodItem.editing = !foodItem.editing" >{{ foodItem.editing ? 'Save': 'Edit' }}</button>`

Comment: Do you want to put both answers together so we can clear this question as answered, others might find this useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data is not saved because the input uses only `value` and not [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html).

v-model create two-way data bindings on form input. (Getting and setting values.)

The button value is not changed because the string was set in the `value` attributes. Instead, putting the string in between  works.

`<button class="button is-fullwidth" v-on:click="foodItem.editing = !foodItem.editing" >{{ foodItem.editing ? 'Save': 'Edit' }}</button>`